# What is the semantic meaning of the position of Unity's transform component?

Tags: unity

What is the meaning of the position in a transform component of a game object in Unity? Is it the center of mass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is the Anchor point. The anchor point is defined by the asset. I believe the default anchor point for 3D assets is the center of gravity. For a 2D object, it is the center of the box.

Note that the anchor point defines the rotation, so that might be important in determining how things work.

It's worth noting that you can change the center of mass from the default, as is shown in the [Unity documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-centerOfMass.html). A rigidbody has a center of mass that can be changed by scripting to better match your requirements.